# How many edges can you add to a tree with $n$ vertices so it stays planar?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How many edges can you add to a tree with $n$ vertices so it stays planar?

My attempt:

Any planar graph has $|E|\le 3n-6$, and tree has $n-1$ edges, so we can add at most $2n-5$ edges.

I tried a lot of examples, and I was always able to add exactly $2n-5$ edges no matter in which order I placed them. But I am stuck without proof.

Comment: Perhaps try induction?  Given a tree on $n$ vertices, consider the smaller tree of $n-1$ vertices formed by removing a leaf from the tree (*note there must always be at least two leafs for a tree on at least two vertices, so such a choice is always possible*).  Now, embellish the smaller tree into a planar graph with by adding the maximum number of edges being $2(n-1)-5$ more edges as per induction hypothesis.  Return the removed leaf to the graph.  Can you add more edges that involve that newly returned leaf while avoiding making the graph non-planar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to JMoravitz, I think I got it.
Suppose That for each $n-1$ tree, we can add $2n-7$ edges. Now we take any $n$ tree and pick any leaf (which exists for any tree with $n>0$). We remove this leaf (or just pretend it doesn't exist) and add 2n-7 edges (which we can do by hypothesis).

Now in this new graph with $n-1$ vertices and $2n-7$ edges, each face  is incident to exactly $3$ vertices, if they were perhaps incident to $4$ vertices, we could just add an edge between $2$ which aren't connected, which would be a contradiction.

Finally we add back the leaf that we removed, which now lives on a face that is incident to his one neighbour and exactly 2 other vertices. We add the 2 edges and complete the proof.